# Hyperledger TPS

Tags: performance, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am doing a Proof of Concept (PoC) based on Hyperledger Blockchain and integrating it with healthcare data (it is an academic project).

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/IBM/BlockchainNetwork-CompositeJourney

Since I am a Windows user and I had no free space left on my SSD to accommodate a Linux Ubuntu dual boot with all ledger stuff, I decided to go with all the POC installation on an "Oracle VM VirtualBox" having all VM files (*.vdi) hosted on my secondary hard drive which is an HDD, not SSD.

That's the tricky part, the "Oracle VM VirtualBox" software itself is installed in my SSD perfectly, but the Linux VM with all the POC is on HDD, which is my secondary hard-drive.

So far I have the Peer working on my VM, and already persisted data on it. My issue/concern is regarding its performance...

I have created a snippet of code in python to benchmark it and I got fabric responses between 2 and 3 seconds per transaction, which I consider an extremely low TPS (Transactions per second) right?

Did I do something wrong? I followed the tutorial step by step, and it is working, but extremally low-performance TPS.

May it be because I have it working on HDD with an Oracle VM?

If I had it all running directly on a SSD with Linux would I get better TPS?

```
 //composer-rest-server endpoint
 url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/Member'

 start = time.time()
 response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
 end = time.time()
 timeTotal = (end - start)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist a lot of factors for low TPS. To make a transaction in Hyperledger Fabric, this goes through several process.

1) Create transaction proposal and send it to all peers endorsement. For example if you have the next policy endorsement:

```
AND('Org1MSP','Org2MSP')
```

At least one peer of each org need to endorse the transactions, for every peer you sended the proporsal they will execute the transaction inside the container and check if it is valid, then if it is valid, they will response with status 200 (This is for every one, individualy).

2) Next step is send the transaction proporsal to the orderer, if is the solo-orderer consensus will be fast than kafka-orderer consensus ([You can check how it works here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/kafka.html#bringing-up-a-kafka-based-ordering-service)). The orderer will create the block and wait few second before send it to each orgs ancho peers. This few second it a very important param in the configtx.yaml file, this is the BatchTimeout, i will quote the definition of the official site of hyperledger fabric:

> Batch Timeout. The amount of time to wait after the first transaction
>   arrives for additional transactions before cutting a block. Decreasing
>   this value will improve latency, but decreasing it too much may
>   decrease throughput by not allowing the block to fill to its maximum
>   capacity.

[Here you can read more.](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/config_update.html#editing-a-config)

EDIT: For default, the batchTimeout value its [2sec](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/configtx.yaml#L214).

3) Now the orderer will send the block to all ancho peers, and they will broadcast the block to all peers of they own organizations, commiting the block and update the state of the ledger.

Of course, if you computer have a low performance this process will be more slow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your repply. Currently I have only 1 Peer and 1 Organization, I named it AdminPeer, its meant to be a really small POC.

I installed composer-rest-server and tested it on the web page and even there the transaction takes like 2s to complete. I am wondering if this low TPS in my case is due to the HDD + VM instead of running directly on SSD...

Comment: Yes, 2 sec to complete the transaction for the batchTimeout, but in 2 sec your orderer node can process a lot of transactions. Try creating you PoC in nodejs and make a lot of transactions with a loop (promises), you will see in 2 sec you make a lot of transactions.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander, I will try re-creating my PoC in nodejs, but I have a last question: in a real-world scenario, imagine we are dealing with healthcare patient data, real-time data processing is a must, how can I batch this information? For example an patient with many sensors reading lots of data per second, every second I should create a new batch and persist all collected data in that second?

Comment: By the way, do you have an Nodejs tutorial example with Hyperledger? I have found this one: https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/NodeSDK-setup

Comment: (1) For a real world scenario you can decrease at minimum value of batchTimeout (I dont know if it accept float numbers). Im not secure, but in healtcare data its extremly delicate. When you send one transaction you sould wait when the block is commited before send the next transaction, because maybe you need to consult the lastest state of the blockchain.

Comment: (2)For example, if you have 2 transaction (A and B) that modify the state of C and they are in the same block, just one will be executed (A or B) because each one taked C.in but have diferent results (A.out or B.out) and maybe this will be dangerous for healt data.  (3) You are using the wrong client: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html . And i have a litte sample here:  https://github.com/Alex99y/fabric-app-example

Answer (score 4):

Generally, TPS in fabric depends on a various factor.

1. Endorsement Policy (Number of endorsing node and policy)
2. Current state Database(Level DB, Couch DB)
3. Resource allocation (Hardware configuration)
4. Block size(Batch size and Batch time (Defined in configtx.yaml file)) and many more factor

The number of transaction that a network can handle and transaction latency are two different things. 
The time between sending transaction and getting a response is a latency
Maximum number of transactions that are getting executed are in second is TPS